Getting a io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error
I have written this simple gRPC code that should run the commit stub on every server. Here is the code -
private Boolean sendCommit(List<Transaction> allTransactions) {
        for (int cur_server_number = 1; cur_server_number <= totalServers; cur_server_number++) {
            if (cur_server_number == SERVER_NUMBER) {
                continue;
            }
            try{
                ManagedChannel channel = serverChannels[cur_server_number];
                DistributedBankGrpc.DistributedBankStub stub = DistributedBankGrpc.newStub(channel);
                BallotData ballot = BallotData.newBuilder()
                        .setBallotNum(this.ballotNumber)
                        .setServerNum(SERVER_NUMBER)
                        .build();
                CommitRequest commitRequest = CommitRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setBallot(ballot)
                        .addAllTransactions(allTransactions)
                        .build();

                final int serverNumber = cur_server_number;
                stub.commit(commitRequest, new StreamObserver<Empty>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Empty emptyResponse) {
                        System.out.println("Commited on server " + serverNumber);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        System.err.println("Commit request to Server " + serverNumber + " failed: " + t.getMessage());
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        System.out.println("Commit request to Server " + serverNumber + " completed.");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("An exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(CommitRequest request, StreamObserver<Empty> responseObserver) {
        BallotData ballot = request.getBallot();
        System.out.println("Got commit - " + ballot);
        this.acceptedBallotNumber = -1;
        this.acceptedServer = -1;
        this.acceptedTransactions = null;
        Empty response = Empty.newBuilder().build();
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

However, everytime I run this, I am getting a  io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error.
I read that we can use latches to wait for individual calls to complete. But this degrades the performance of the application. I want to implement something like a "Fire and Forget", where I send RPC calls to the servers and immediately return from the calling function.
How can I implement this?

I believe exploring ScheduledExecutorService will be worth here.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
